# How to implement hosted service for a singleton job that can be started and stopped?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I want to create a hosted service that can be started and stopped through user interaction. The service should **not** be started automatically, attempting to start it when it is already started should have no effect, and it should be possible to check whether the service is currently running. The service will eventually finish running, at which point it should transition to the stopped state until it is started again.

Below is my attempt at implementing this and it seems to be working, but I was wondering if there are any glaring flaws with this approach, or if there is a simpler solution.

There are two parts, a singleton `FooJobControl` which can be injected into controllers to start or stop the service, and the hosted service `FooJob` which waits for a signal from `FooJobControl` to start working and signals when it has stopped.

in Startup.cs

```
services.AddHostedService<FooJob>();
services.AddSingleton<FooJobControl>();
```

FooJobControl.cs

```
public class FooJobControl
{
    private AsyncAutoResetEvent _evt = new AsyncAutoResetEvent(false);
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private object _sync = new object();

    public void Start()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_cts == null)
            {
                _evt.Set();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_cts != null)
            {
                _cts.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _cts != null && !_cts.IsCancellationRequested;
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<CancellationToken> JobStart(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _evt.WaitAsync(stoppingToken);

        lock (_sync)
        {
            _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(stoppingToken);
            return _cts.Token;
        }
    }

    public void JobEnd()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            _cts = null;
        }
    }
}
```

FooJob.cs

```
public class FooJob : BackgroundService
{
    private FooJobControl _control;
    private ILogger<FooJob> _logger;

    public FooJob(ILogger<FooJob> logger, FooJobControl control)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _control = control;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            CancellationToken token = await _control.JobStart(stoppingToken);
            try
            {
                await DoWork(token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to run job");
            }
            _control.JobEnd();
        }
    }

    private async Task DoWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("DoWork Cancelled");
                return;
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("DoWork " + i);

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hosted services are not meant to be stopped and started randomly. They have a lifetime that matches the application lifetime, i.e. they start when your application starts and they stop when your application stops. However, they don't necessarily need to *do* anything while "running". In the case of a timed service, the timer will kick off work at the appropriate interval. In the cased of a queue service, items being added to the queue kicks off the work. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I guess I'm not really starting and stopping the hosted service itself, but stopping and starting its processing. I just want to be able to start, stop, and check the status of some singleton background task. Maybe hosted services are not the right tool. If HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem was available in .NET Core, maybe I could use a wrapper around it that prevents it from being queued twice and tracks when it completes, but it isn't.